# How to measure the role of btrfs in SSD wear on my PC?

Tags: ext4, btrfs, ssd, storage, samsung

I've used btrfs for my encrypted partitions (luks) on Samsung EVO SSDs. The disks failed faster than expected. How can I assess whether e.g. ext4 would be more reliable on these disks for my usage, or what usage is more likely to contribute to their wear level?

### Background

After about 2 year of use as root and home disk on my desktop PC, my Samsung SSD 870 EVO 500GB started failing, with hundreds of bad blocks and thousands of uncorrectable errors:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.2.15-100.fc36.x86_64] (local build)

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 500GB
Firmware Version: SVT01B6Q

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                                        the read element of the test failed.

ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       19378
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       69
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       44
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   065   065   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       200
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2696
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       59
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       83504703737
```

The disk was rather busy, but well under the [warranty limits](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/warranty/) of 5 years or 300 TB TBW.

Its predecessor was a Samsung 850 EVO 250 GB and was in a similar state after 5 years of use. Maybe the new disk was just worse than the previous, but I started wondering whether there's a common factor.

One thing they shared is that I've installed Fedora on them, and recently Fedora started using btrfs by default (at least for luks filesystems), instead of ext4 (I believe the previous disk had ext4 most of its life). Fedora 38 for example creates this layout by default:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                   8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                8:1    0   600M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                8:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                8:3    0 464,2G  0 part  
  └─luks-<redacted> 253:0    0 464,2G  0 crypt /home
                     /
$ mount | grep luks
/dev/mapper/luks-<redacted> on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,compress=zstd:1,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=257,subvol=/root)
/dev/mapper/luks-<redacted> on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,compress=zstd:1,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=256,subvol=/home)
$ mount | grep sda
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=winnt,errors=remount-ro)
```

A few years back it was similar but without [compression](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Compression.html) and some other btrfs parameters.

The btrfs documentation, after a discussion of COW (copy on write), contains a number of [warnings on SSDs](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Hardware.html#solid-state-drives-ssd):

> Writing “too much” distinct data (e.g. encrypted) may render the internal deduplication ineffective and lead to a lot of rewrites and increased wear of the memory cells.
> It’s not possible to reliably determine the expected lifetime of an SSD due to lack of information about how it works or due to lack of reliable stats provided by the device.
> Only users who consume 50 to 100% of the SSD’s actual lifetime writes need to be concerned by the write amplification of btrfs DUP metadata.

So it sounds like I've reached over 50 % of the disks' actual lifetime despite my writes being an order of magnitude less than what promised by the warranty, and I *should* worry about SSD wear with btrfs.

#### Usage patterns

I now notice that you're supposed to run a [btrfs scrub](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Scrub.html) monthly and also after events like power outages:

> The user is supposed to run it manually or via a periodic system service. The recommended period is a month but could be less.

I never did that. The most frequently accessed files get checked and repaired anyway at some point. My files which got corrupted tended to be on the older and less accessed side.

(It would be strange if this mattered though. Another SSD of mine with luks+lvm+ext4 has over 10k powercycles, accorting to SMART, and no issues whatsoever.)

### Possible ideas

It's common for people to advise against running databases or other similarly write-intensive loads on btrfs.

I don't know how true/current said advice is, but I don't run any database on my PC. On the other hand, the previous disk's most devastating failures where in a region used by Thunderbird for its message storage (which was a few GB worth of mbox files; I've since switched to Maildir). I wonder whether there are some database-like loads on my PC which I could do without, or move to another filesystem. (I've already disabled baloo.)

Is there some benchmarking tool or utility to tell which applications are producing most writes (or most potential wear) to the filesystem?

Alternatively, is there a benchmarking tool or utility to stress test a certain filesystem-disk combination and see the impact on the disk's self-reported wear in the various cases?

Comment: I saw some previous discussion at * https://superuser.com/a/1083862/283120 * https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106678/59808 * https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644509/59808

Comment: Just a note: Encrpytion and COW-filesystems (like BTRFS) can generate in general more writes, you should always try to use the `noatime` mount option if possible.

Comment: @paladin Fascinating suggestion. I had not considered that updating metadata could also cause intense rewrites at the physical level. (I hope btrfs doesn't write the entire file again just to update its metadata! But who knows what the firmware actually does.) Is there a way to measure the impact of a switch to `noatime`? Should I just try it out for a few days and see whether SMART statistics show a lower-than-average increase in`Total_LBAs_Written`?

Comment: It's possible to measure it, but it's difficult. If you just want to see the difference between a `noatime` and a `atime` or `relatime` mounted BTRFS filesystem, just measure time via `time { grep --recursive ifeellucky /*; sync; }`, please take note that this command greps the entire root filesystem, please also take note that every greped file will generate a write operation when using a BTRFS filesystem which is not mounted using `noatime`. PS there are several articles about this, I recommend using `noatime` for most parts of a BTRFS filesystem, you can mount subvolumes for `relatime`

Comment: PPS `relatime` mounted filesystem will generate delayed inode update writes, so it might not be comparable well to `noatime` mounted filesystems, but at some point, the writes need to be done

Answer (score 1):

The early to mid-2021 Samsung 870 EVO SSDs [often fail early](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/samsung-870-evo-beware-certain-batches-prone-to-failure.291504)
because of uncorrectable errors.

I recommend that you just return the drive. 
You'll need to call Samsung to get an [RMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_merchandise_authorization) for the SSD;
don't try to send an email.

Comment: What is “RMA”?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks! I did manage to return the drive. Where I am (Finland, EU), I didn't find a way to call them, but email worked very fast.